# How to make the pairwise product of two lists in OCaml?

Tags: list, ocaml, product

**How to write function that makes cartesian product of two lists?**

*For example, I have this*

```
[a;b;c][d;e;f]
```

*And need this*

```
[a*d;b*e;c*f]
```

?

Comment: I haven't done any OCaml development, but given its functional background, the function you're looking for is usually named `zip`.  It looks like there's a function in list named `combine` that seems to match your intention, according to [this site](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html), but I have no idea how authoritative that reference is.

Comment: Yes, List.combine does this. But this looks like homework, in which case functions in the List module are probably forbidden....?

Comment: This is not the cartesian product! The cartesian product would be: [(a,d);(a,e);(a,f);(b,d);(b,e);(b,f);(c,d);(c,e);(c,f)]

Comment: I'm not downvoting for the homework question. I'm downvoting because this came up as search results for cartesian product in OCaml, yet the question is about pairwise products.

Comment: I understand the close vote, but "off-topic" is the wrong reason.  Just look at the description of that reason.  It should have been closed for not showing sufficient effort, adding a MWE, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The function `combine` in the `List` module seems to fit your requirements. [See documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html)

Sample Usage:

```
let x = [1; 2; 3]
let y = [4; 5; 6]
List.combine x y    (* => [(1, 4); (2, 5); (3, 6)] *)
```

Note that the function requires both lists to be the same length.  If you want it to be more flexible, you may need to write this yourself.

If you wanted to combine the lists using an arbitrary function, one possible way would be to use `List.combine` to create this list of tuples, then use `List.map` to create a result from each pair.

Comment: thanks a lot, but this function should be more common, so I can't declare lists

Comment: Sorry, not gonna help you do homework for you.  Use pattern matching to help write a recursive function.